# Parts broken in TOC with Polyglossia / French

Tags: table-of-contents, polyglossia, french

I'm trying to remove "Première Partie" from the TOC, I just would like the part title. It works well if I remove polyglossia, but I need it for Asian languages in my document.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Le début}

Salut

\end{document}
```

And the output (with xelatex):
[image]

I know that polyglossia/French is messing up with \thepart, but the solution is beyond my latex level!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typesetting of part titles in the table of contents uses `\partnumberlinebox`, which is defined to typeset its contents in a box with fixed width. You can redefine to take all the space it needs. I added an em-dash for separation.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\setheadfoot{14.4pt}{\footskip} % remove the warning

% fix the typesetting of the part number
\renewcommand\partnumberlinebox[2]{#2\ ---\ }

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Le début}

Salut

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @egreg! Actually I wanted to completely remove the "Première partie", so I used `\renewcommand\partnumberlinebox[2]{}`. You made my day.